# ACTION_CALL doesn't works properly

Tags: android

I want to make a call on click of a button in a menu.
The action works,but not properly because when I click the button starts a blank page,when I click back button,the call starts!I don't find the error,can you help me,please?

Here's my code:

```
/*Fare una telefonata*/
private void onCall() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                123);
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:3314617839")));
    }
}
/*Dopo il risulato della richiesta di permesso*/
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 123:
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                onCall();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Call Permission Not Granted");
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The button is:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id=item.getItemId();
    switch(id)
    {
        case R.id.ContConc:
            onCall();
```

I have the permission on the manifest,in fact the call starts,but I think there's something redundant maybe,I really don't know!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you use ACTION_DIAL, it will save you all the asking for permission thing:

```
public static void dialNumber(Context context, String number) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

but if you really want to call, you will need to do more work, unless your 
        targetSdkVersion is below 23. For 23 and higher you will need to implement a [Permission handler](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Then you can use a method like this one:

```
 public static void callNumber(Context context, String number){
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ number));

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            context.startActivity(callIntent);
        }
```

Comment: @MariaNovellaMadia i edited my answer if you want to check

Answer (score 1):

I was doing the same thing ome time ago and it didn't work for me either so I ended up doing this:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {
int id=item.getItemId();
switch(id)
{
    case R.id.ContConc:
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number = "+31612345678";
            Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
            Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, call);
            startActivity(call);
```

it is not the exact same thing as you want, beacause this will take you to the caller app with the phone number that you put into the number variable.

You also wont have to ask permission

Hope this helps!